# Sonar ant task: PmdSensor throws UnsupportedOperationException after update to SonarQube 4.4

Tags: ant, sonarqube, pmd

After updating my SonarQube installation from 4.1.1 to 4.4 I always get the error

```
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.XmlParserException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported since v4.2. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/API+Changes
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor.analyse(PmdSensor.java:55)
    ...
```

when running the ant task configured as suggested in:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task
and
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Ant+Task

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: What version of the pmd plugin are you using ? Have you upgraded it to the latest version ?

Comment: Pls check this http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix

@benzonico I am having the same issue,  
Here is the version details -  
  sonarqube is 4.4, sonar-pmd-plugin-2.0.jar. I am going to try with sonar-pmd-plugin-2.2.jar now, but I think I ran into an issue with that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This matrix should be a good reference when you do an upgrade - http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix

Today I upgraded sonarqube to v 4.4 and got it fully working with this set of plugins -

SONARQUBE PLUGINS

1. Checkstyle  2.1
2. Findbugs    2.4 (recommended version is 3.0 but my source code is Java 1.6)
3. Java    2.4
4. PMD 2.2

I was facing exactly the same issue as you were, so I m hoping that this combination should work for you as well! Goodluck!